# Storing a New Instance In a Stream

Tags: java, for-loop, collections, java-8, java-stream

If I have a stream of objects, can I turn it into a collection of another object? So if I have a collection of Strings can I turn it into a collection of Persons? Something like:

`strings.stream().forEach((string) -> {new Person(string);}).collect(Collectors.toList());`

```
public class Person{
private String name;

Person(String name){
this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes, I suggest you try it with `map()` instead of `forEach`

```
List<Person> people = strings.stream()
                             .map(Person::new)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: while `Person::new` does the same thing as `s -> new Person(s)` it is not exactly the same.  The `Person::new` doesn't create a lambda method but the latter does.  In the byte code, you will see a synthetic method which contains the implementation.

Answer (score 5):

That's what `map` is for :

```
List<Person> persons = strings.stream()
                      .map(s -> new Person(s))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```